# Mysql check limit 3 already in db

Tags: sql

I wanna to make limit check. Primary - check if name already in last 3 lines. How to make?

```
$connect     = db_connect();
$query       = "SELECT * FROM `lastest` WHERE `name` LIKE '" .$name. "'";
$result = db_query($query, $connect);

if ($result) {
die('Already in db.'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column id is "id" :

Googling "sql get last rows" (without quotes) leads to this page :

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

Pick up your db, and customize the request to get the 3 last lines. Then write a request querying a sub-request (this one who gets the 3 last lines) with your where statment...

So, assuming that your primary key is "id" :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT id, name
   FROM lastest
   ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 3) sub_lastest
WHERE `name` LIKE [name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check is_exists column, this what i can suggest to you:

is_exists = 1 => Name exists

is_exists = 0 => Name doesn't exists

---

```
SELECT count(*) as is_exists,GROUP_CONCAT(`fname`) as a 
FROM test.users 
HAVING a LIKE "% YOUR_NAME %" 
ORDER BY `fname` DESC 
LIMIT 3 ;
```

---

Try it and let me know if it was help you

Don't hesitate ask any questions

Good luck